# Toggle input element's disabled attribute depending on a checkbox value using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a form in which one text input field will have `disabled` attribute if a checkbox is checked. I tried:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isChecked: false,
    name: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="name" :class="{disabled: isChecked}" placeholder="disabled if box checked">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isChecked">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried `:disabled=isChecked` instead of `:class="{disabled: isChecked}"` ?

Comment: `:disabled=isChecked` does the job. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind if I create an answer so people who find this question can get the answer more easily ?

Comment: Definitely. I was about to ask you to post an answer, maybe with a bit elaboration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead if using a conditional class, you can just use the property `disabled` and make it dynamic by adding a `:` in front of it and binding it to the `isChecked` variable. Your code will then look like this :

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="name" :disabled="isChecked" placeholder="disabled if box checked">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="isChecked">
</div>
```

Comment: There are missing quotations in `:disabled="isChecked"`

Comment: According to the doc it's not required, but is said to be avoided as it makes developpers get the habit of not adding spaces in the attributes values (https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Quoted-attribute-values-strongly-recommended). Thanks for pointing it out, I never really thought about that, I will add them.